# Add object to array on select from dropdown. Remove from array if un selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a function with params and I am doing a forEach loop to add all the values from the loop.

obj:

```
'values':
[
{date: '10-10-2020', abc: 1, xyz: 5, pqr: 6, jkl: 1, mno: 9},
{date: '10-07-2020', abc: 3, xyz: 4, pqr: 1, jkl: 6, mno: 1},
{date: '10-09-2020', abc: 7, xyz: 2, pqr: 9, jkl: 3, mno: 0},
]
colors=['#000', '#fff', '#f8f8f8']
```

```
const data = (sd) => Object.entries(obj).map(([k, g]) => ({
  ['name']: k,
  ['data']: g.map(entry => entry[sd]),
  ['type']: sd,
  ['color']: colors[i++ % colors.length],
}));
```

I then push them into a giant array:

```
let arr = ['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr', 'jkl', 'mno'];
let x = [];
arr.forEach(y => {
  x = [...x, ...data(y)];
});
```

I also have a multiselect dropdown with the array values as items. The first one is selected on load.

Is there any way for me to already have the first item of array populated in `x` and on select add the corresponding item to the array. On unselect I would like remove the item from array. I am unsure on how to go from here.

My dropdown code:

```
arr.forEach(c => {$(`#mydropdown`).append(`<option value='${c}'>${c}</option>`);});
$(`select#mydropdown option[value='abc']`).prop('selected', 'selected');

$(`#mydropdown`).on('change', function() {
   $('option:selected', this).each(function() {
      // Add to 'x'
   });
});
```

Is there any way for me to add/remove to `x` by clicking and unlocking?

Comment: What is the value of `obj` (as seen in data function)?

Comment: @Chase, I have added that. colors is an array of hex codes

Comment: That's still pretty opaque, and other variables like `colors` are missing. It would be advisable to provide a minimal but functional reproducible example using the code snippets tool that answers could modify and extend to meet your needs. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: @Chase, SOrry about that. I have added more details about `obj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for something like this. For simplicity of managing the state, it seems easiest to just recreate X when selected values change.

```js
const obj = {
'values': [
  {date: '10-10-2020', abc: 1, xyz: 5, pqr: 6, jkl: 1, mno: 9},
  {date: '10-07-2020', abc: 3, xyz: 4, pqr: 1, jkl: 6, mno: 1},
  {date: '10-09-2020', abc: 7, xyz: 2, pqr: 9, jkl: 3, mno: 0},
  ]
};

const colors=['#000', '#fff', '#f8f8f8'];

let i = 0;
const data = (sd) => Object.entries(obj).map(([k, g]) => ({
  ['name']: k,
  ['data']: g.map(entry => entry[sd]),
  ['type']: sd,
  ['color']: colors[i++ % colors.length],
}));

let arr = ['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr', 'jkl', 'mno'];
let x = [data('abc')];
console.log(x);
/*
arr.forEach(y => {
  x = [...x, ...data(y)];
});
*/

arr.forEach(c => {$(`#mydropdown`).append(`<option value='${c}'>${c}</option>`);});
$(`select#mydropdown option[value='abc']`).prop('selected', 'selected');

$(`#mydropdown`).on('change', function() {
   x = [];
   $('option:selected', this).each(function() {
      x.push(data($(this).val()));
   });
   console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select multiple id="mydropdown">
</select>
```